# Listener keydown : backspace and field length

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm wondering why my Backspace touch increment my `countLetters` variable.

I ask him to return the number of characters, without ever manually incrementing the variable. Why does the backspace key increment **my variable once**, before working properly?

```
const $textareas   = document.querySelectorAll('.js-textarea');

$textareas.forEach(function($textarea) {
  $textarea.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    let max = 100;
    let countLetters = $textarea.value.length;

    let $meta = this.nextSibling.nextSibling; // = meta

    $meta.innerHTML = countLetters + ' / ' + max;

    if (countLetters >= max) {
      $textarea.value.toString().substring(0, max);
    }

    if (event.which != 46) {
      return;
    }

    // Disabled <textarea>
    if (countLetters >= max) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  });
});
```

Demo is available on Here's [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VOdzdw)!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The value of the text area is changed after your `keydown` handler runs. You could use the `input` event instead.

Here is an example:

```
const max = 100;
$textarea.addEventListener('input', function() {
    const countLetters = $textarea.value.length;
    const $meta = this.nextSibling.nextSibling;
    $meta.innerHTML = countLetters + ' / ' + max;
});
$textarea.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    if ($textarea.value.length >= max && event.key === 'Backspace') {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Keydown fires before letter was added or removed in case of backspace. Use `keyup` instead of `keydown`.